# Airflow installation with helm on kubernetes cluster is failing with db migration pod

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, kubernetesexecutor

**Error:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Steps:**

I have downloaded the helm chart from here https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases/tag/helm-chart/1.8.0 (Under Assets, Source code zip).

Added following extra params to default values.yaml,

```js
createUserJob:
  useHelmHooks: false
migrateDatabaseJob:
  useHelmHooks: false
dags:
  gitSync:
    enabled: true
    #all data....
airflow:
  extraEnv:
    - name: AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND
      value: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
ingress:
  web:
    tls:
      enabled: true
      secretName: wildcard-tls-cert
      host: "mydns.com"
      path: "/airflow"
```

I also need KubernetesExecutor hence using https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/sample-values-KubernetesExecutor.yaml as k8sExecutor.yaml

Installing using following command,

> helm install my-airflow airflow-8.6.1/airflow/ --values values.yaml
> --values k8sExecutor.yaml -n mynamespace

Answer (score -1):

It worked when I tried the following way,

> ```
> helm repo add airflow-repo https://airflow-helm.github.io/charts
> helm install my-airflow airflow-repo/airflow --version 8.6.1 --values k8sExecutor.yaml --values values.yaml
> ```

values.yaml - has only overridden parameters